# Why wrap a dolphin in wet towels?

Tags: zoology, mammals

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yz6ax4rRrvI), a dolphin jumps into a vessel.  Even though the guides know they will be quickly helping the dolphin back into the water, they first make sure they wrap the mammal with wet towels.

Why did they rush so quickly to wrap the dolphin with wet towels?  Is there something about the biology of dolphins that made that action essential?

Comment: I don't have any scientific sources for this, which is why this is a comment instead of an answer, but it's my understanding that their skin can dry out very quickly, killing the skin cells and reducing its flexibility. Dolphins don't have [sebaceous glands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebaceous_gland) or other forms of lubricating and moisturizing their skin, so drying could potentially be rather harmful, not to mention painful.

Comment: @MattDMo Thanks.  Before posting, I asked a friend, and she said something very similar.  She said "it hurts them to go dry", but she didn't know why.